# Dahlia or a weed?

Tags: identification, dahlias

These came up along with my other dahlias this year and I don't know if they are a weed or not. I accidentally dug up a bunch of tubers thinking they were weeds a bit ago and now I'm a bit scared lol. Any help is greatly appreciated.[image: dhaliaweed]

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not a dahlia. They look like something we call Burnweed where I live - if you let them flower, do NOT let them set seed